# Why is Valgrind memcheck running numerous times on my Ruby program?

Tags: ruby, valgrind

When I run my Ruby program with the following command:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck ruby hello.rb
```

I get outputs for heap, leak and error summaries exactly four times every time.

[Full output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1hsa.png)

All my Ruby program does is that it loads a text file containing 10,000 characters. Memcheck worked just fine for my similar Python programs when I ran them with the same commands. Why do I get four outputs? Is some of them indicating the correct amount of memory used? I'm measuring memory consumptions for my master's thesis, so I really need to find out what's causing this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default, valgrind does not 'follow' child processes (i.e. does not follow
the forked children that calls an exec system call).

But by default, a forked child that does not exec will output some results.
Using --child-silent-after-fork=yes should make the output of the forking not
exec-ing child disappear.

Comment: That didn't work, it simply paused before giving me any output on heap, leak and error summaries

Comment: At this stage, this looks like an unexpected behaviour or interaction of valgrind and ruby.  Enable more debugging in valgrind (e.g. -v -v -v -d -d -d --trace-syscalls=yes) and report a bug on valgrind bugzilla, attaching the output. Thanks